# Pass objects between R and Python in memory

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am working on a workflow that contains both Python and R scripts. In its current state, original input in the form of a csv file is read into Python, the outputs are then written to a csv which is ingested into R, and the outputs of the R script are once again written to csv and written to Python.

The data frames which are being worked on are very large (>60GB) so understandably the process takes a long time and I would like to speed it up. Below I have listed out what I have attempted and the results:

1. **Use parquet format:** This solution is not viable as it requires Spark on the R side of things
2. **Utilize the feather format:** This solution has not been viable as feather files have issues with extremely large files (>300,000,000 records) in its current state

Currently I am investigating the idea of keeping a data frame in working memory and somehow passing the object between R and Python without going through an i/o process of writing and reading a file. I have searched online but have not found a suitable solution. I am checking to see if anyone here has experience with this sort of project or any other types of suggestions. To this point, the closest thing I have found was combining the Python and R script into a single notebook/markdown style script with the ability to interpret both R and Python code, however I am looking for a solution which will keep the scripts more modularized. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That sounds hard. I'm lazy. I would just move to HDF5 rather than csv or something.

Comment: "Currently I am investigating the idea of keeping a data frame in working memory and somehow passing the object between R and Python without going through an i/o process of writing and reading a file. " I doubt there is any existing solution that does that. There's no simply way of doing that - a data-frame is a complex object in both languages. A question, though, what type of data are you working with? You *may* be able to convert to a primitive array and share that. That would be easier, for sure.

Comment: help with https://github.com/jimhester/rarrow, perhaps? then you can use the same in-memory structures.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Arrow was designed to solve this problem. There are no R bindings yet. You might not want to be so definitive abt things you haven't fully researched.

Comment: Justin: you could try using Apache Drill as a unifying data access component. It can easily handle that data and has python & R packages.

Comment: @hrbrmstr well I thought that the OP *already mentioned* feather. As I had understood it, feather was the project that was trying to create an R/Python intra-operable binary serialization format based on Apache Arrow. But I think my main misunderstanding is exactly what the OP is looking for - if it is actually sharing memory between an R and Python process, that is quite different than serializing and sending a binary blob between processes.

Comment: Mebbe read vs continue to opine @juanpa.arrivillaga. Not serialization. Active memory. That's what Arrow's main function is. Feather is one use. Not the main use.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow currently supports by Python and R (bindings for both, in other words).

See the following article for an introduction to how to solve this problem:

- https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/python.html